# EntityState.Deleted on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running into a strange case: when I do SaveChanges on my context, subyacent record is deleted. In order to know what is going on I have overrided SaveChanges:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entity.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

but still can't find what is wrong.

Comment: subyacent? did you mean subsequent? What error is happening, can we see the code where you are calling SaveChnages from when the error occurs

Comment: there is noting that unusual and there is no error sometimes im getting into the delete without any delete opertion after update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that i did lazy load on my dbcontext , after open and close connection for each method i didnt have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, your delete is cascading (IE deleting other records that are related to the record your deleting), look at your table relationships and the properties.